# Google Prettify with Lex tag Parser Code

Tags: html, prettify, google-code-prettify

It appears Google Prettify doesn't like lex parser tags.  I've added the following to a blog post that uses prettify to format code:

```
<!-- Content -->
<div id="content" class="grid_8 suffix_1">
    {{ widgets:area slug="above-body" }}
    {{ template:body }}
</div>
```

The two lines of lex code (in between the {{ }}) disappear in the post.  If I change them to single brackets, they look OK.  I assume prettify uses a similar sort of tagging syntax, which would explain this.  Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't link to your blog post and it seems to prettify just fine on this page, so I can't really diagnose the problem, but if you want to file a bug with your HTML at http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list I'll take a look.

Comment: I agree.. it prettifies fine on this page.  I didn't add the code to the article because of the disappearing text ( used a screenshot instead ).  I wanted to verify prettify didn't actually use double brackets for something before I scoped the issue more.  I'll do that now & report back.

Comment: I believe I've ruled out Prettify as the issue (removed PrettyPrint() call from the body tag.  The code still disappears.)  I believe it's a PyroCMS issue.  Thanks for your feedback & sorry if I wasted any of your time.

Comment: @DanB.  No problem.  Happy blogging.  Now that I think about it, you might look at template systems as a culprit.  Some, like jQuery templates (see ["Template Tags"](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/)) use pairs of curly brackets.

Comment: The template system PyroCMS uses is the culprit.  Apparently you can add template tags around your template tags to prevent them from being parsed (and therefor shown in <pre> tags for example. )  [SOURCE](https://www.pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/21781).